# Custom page in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I created a new custom page with a non-ActiveAdmin controller. The view is at
`app/views/messages/new.html.erb` instead of `app/views/admin/help`.
I tried to reference the template path:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Help" do
  content do
    render :partial => 'messages/new'
  end
end
```

but didn't work (ActionView::MissingTemplate).

Comment: Have you tried using `render 'messages/new'` ?

Answer (score 0):

try to add this view in admin folder like below

```
app/views/admin/messages/new.html.erb
```